# Excel CountIFS formula - too few arguments

Tags: excel, countif

trying to use the formula below in my conditional formatting I'm getting a 'too few arguments' error -

=COUNTIFS(Ratecard!E:E,AW3, Ratecard!G:G,BA3, AN3 > 0) = 0

Any thoughts?

Comment: the last 3 criteria, what are you trying to do with it? Please explain what you want your formula to do.

Comment: Hey Scott,The first criteria checks that the value in AW3 exists in column E of Ratecard, the second value checks that the value in BA3 exists in column G of Ratecard - At this point if both values don't exist then 0 -- This works.

Comment: The third is checking that the associated hours are greater than zero. Basically I want to highlight in Red on a Time extract where the rate is wrong and hours are greater than zero, or in orange where the rate is wrong, but the hours are zero..

Comment: The other thing is that I can't copy the conditional formula down... :(

Comment: This=COUNTIFS(Ratecard!E:E,AW3, Ratecard!G:G,BA3) = 0

Comment: Then you would want to use and OR()... :  `=OR(COUNTIFS(Ratecard!E:E,AW3, Ratecard!G:G,BA3)=0,AN3>0)`

Comment: works fine, its only when I add the 'AN3 > 0' that it fails.. but even the above won't copy down

Comment: That works a treat - gives True or False (Thank you) ,.. however, what I really want to do is --

If AN3 > 0 and Countifs = 0 'Red'
IF AN3 = 0 and Countifs = 0 'Orange' 

Any thoughts ?

Thank you

Comment: sure, you will need two formulas each with their own rule in conditional formatting.  use the same formula, just change the `>` to `=` for the second.

Comment: Sorry,..

There's a third option here!  Which is no formatting, -- IF AN3 > 0 and Countifs > 0 - no formatting - Everything is correct....

Comment: Each option gets it's own rule with its own formula.  Change the formula above to your needs for each.

Comment: Many thanks Scott, got that working perfectly now.